# C to Python via SWIG: can't get void** parameters to hold their value

Tags: python, c, swig, word-wrap

I have a C interface that looks like this (simplified):

```
extern bool Operation(void ** ppData);
extern float GetFieldValue(void* pData);
extern void Cleanup(p);
```

which is used as follows:

```
void * p = NULL;
float theAnswer = 0.0f;
if (Operation(&p))
{
   theAnswer = GetFieldValue(p);
   Cleanup(p);
}
```

You'll note that Operation() allocates the buffer p, that GetFieldValue queries p, and that Cleanup frees p. I don't have any control over the C interface -- that code is widely used elsewhere.

I'd like to call this code from Python via [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), but I was unable to find any good examples of how to pass a pointer to a pointer -- and retrieve its value.

I think the correct way to do this is by use of typemaps, so I defined an interface that would automatically dereference p for me on the C side:

```
%typemap(in) void** {
   $1 = (void**)&($input);
}
```

However, I was unable to get the following python code to work:

```
import test
p = None
theAnswer = 0.0f
if test.Operation(p):
   theAnswer = test.GetFieldValue(p)
   test.Cleanup(p)
```

After calling test.Operation(), p always kept its initial value of None.

Any help with figuring out the correct way to do this in SWIG would be much appreciated. Otherwise, I'm likely to just write a C++ wrapper around the C code that stops Python from having to deal with the pointer. And then wrap *that* wrapper with SWIG. Somebody stop me!

Edit:

Thanks to [Jorenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7161/jorenko), I now have the following SWIG interface:

```
% module Test 
%typemap (in,numinputs=0) void** (void *temp)
{
    $1 = &temp;
}

%typemap (argout) void**
{
    PyObject *obj = PyCObject_FromVoidPtr(*$1, Cleanup);
    $result = PyTuple_Pack(2, $result, obj);
}
%{
extern bool Operation(void ** ppData); 
extern float GetFieldValue(void *p); 
extern void Cleanup(void *p);
%} 
%inline 
%{ 
    float gfv(void *p){ return GetFieldValue(p);} 
%} 

%typemap (in) void*
{
    if (PyCObject_Check($input))
    {
        $1 = PyCObject_AsVoidPtr($input);
    }
}
```

The python code that uses this SWIG interface is as follows:

```
import test 
success, p = test.Operation()
if success:
   f = test.GetFieldValue(p) # This doesn't work 
   f = test.gvp(p) # This works! 
   test.Cleanup(p)
```

Oddly, in the python code, test.GetFieldValue(p) returns gibberish, but test.gfv(p) returns the correct value. I've inserting debugging code into the typemap for void*, and both have the same value of p! The call Any ideas about that?

**Update:** I've decided to use ctypes. MUCH easier.

Comment: 1. `p` is simultaneously 'void**' and 'void*' in your Python code 2. `None` is immutable therefore `p` (an object it refers to) won't change no matter what (though you may bind `p` to a different object (using `=`)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with theller, you should use ctypes instead. It's always easier than thinking about typemaps.

But, if you're dead set on using swig, what you need to do is make a typemap for `void**` that RETURNS the newly allocated `void*`:

```
%typemap (in,numinputs=0) void** (void *temp)
{
    $1 = &temp;
}

%typemap (argout) void**
{
    PyObject *obj = PyCObject_FromVoidPtr(*$1);
    $result = PyTuple_Pack(2, $result, obj);
}
```

Then your python looks like:

```
import test
success, p = test.Operation()
theAnswer = 0.0f
if success:
   theAnswer = test.GetFieldValue(p)
   test.Cleanup(p)
```

Edit:

I'd expect swig to handle a simple by-value `void*` arg gracefully on its own, but just in case, here's swig code to wrap the `void*` for GetFieldValue() and Cleanup():

```
%typemap (in) void*
{
    $1 = PyCObject_AsVoidPtr($input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swig. test.Operation() now works, but I'm having trouble calling test.GetFieldValue(p) from the python code. Do I need a typemap for void* as well?

Comment: Weird. I added a typemap for that to my answer, just in case, though I  haven't had a chance to test it...

Comment: Thanks -- so this is a bit weird. Without the typemap, GetFieldValue claims that p is null. With the typemap, there are no complaints, but I get back a garbage value in theAnswer.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that the typemaps are actual C snippets that get inserted before/after the wrapped function call. If you like you can put debug prints, etc there to try to work out what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks -- Here's the interface (+ your stuff):
% module Test
%{
    extern float GetFieldValue(void *p);
}%
%inline %{ float gfv(void *p){ return GetFieldValue(p);} %}

Oddly, test.GetFieldValue(p) returns gibberish, but test.gfv(p) returns the correct value. But both have the same value of p!

Comment: Sorry that last comment was really hard to read -- I've updated the question so the interface code is readable.

Comment: I've updated the question with the calling code (at the bottom). Basically, I'm calling gvf and GetFieldValue() the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Would you be willing to use ctypes?  Here is sample code that should work (although it is untested):

```
from ctypes import *

test = cdll("mydll")

test.Operation.restype = c_bool
test.Operation.argtypes = [POINTER(c_void_p)]

test.GetFieldValue.restype = c_float
test.GetFieldValue.argtypes = [c_void_p]

test.Cleanup.restype = None
test.Cleanup.argtypes = [c_void_p]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = c_void_p()
    if test.Operation(byref(p)):
        theAnswer = test.GetFieldValue(p)
        test.Cleanup(p)
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'd prefer to use SWIG if I can, but if it doesn't work out, I may consider ctypes.